# how to get the categories for a single product in a hierarchical way

Tags: customization, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, single, hierarchical

It's the first time I write here, but I really appreciate your work from long time.

Well, I know there is a [very similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/148959/list-categories-of-the-parent-category-of-the-current-category), but I can't get out the solution for my particular case.

In a structure of
 `super-cat > parent-cat > cat > subcat`

I have **products** which can be assigned in many categories, even many super categories.

I would like to have the categories displayed in hierarchical way and formatted if possible as a  `<ul><li>`  list without the link to the category archive.

I checked out the `hierarchical_category_tree` function, it would be good, but it shows the entire tree of categroies while I need to have displayed just the categories the current product is in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?